# Unexpected delay when doing a http GET in a localhost site

Tags: wordpress, performance, http, get, localhost

I'm debugging a Wordpress offline site (localhost). It's been a few months since I'm not working on it and now I'm getting a delay of about 2 seconds on each request at https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js , something that never happened before.

What's bugging me it's that other GET requests such as http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js ,for example, are not experiencing delays. What I see in the Firefox console is a GET to the google address which has a 2293ms delay. All the other GETs towards other addresses has a 0ms delay

Already tried purging the cache and using another browser to no avail.

It doesn't seem a Wordpress/PHP problem though because I get the same behavior if I enter that address in the Firefox address bar.

Any ideas ? Thanks!